# What does 'Return' do exactly, and where and when should I use it?

Tags: python, for-loop, return

What's the difference between where I put the 'return'? It gives me a different answer and I'm really confused.

Correct:

```
def grades_sum(scores):
  total=0
  for i in scores:
    total+=i
  return total
  print (total)

grades_sum(grades)
```

and a wrong answer:

```
def grades_sum(scores):
  total=0
  for i in scores:
    total+=i
    return total
  print (total)

grades_sum(grades)
```

Also, why does including a return in this variance function give me the wrong answer:

```
def grades_variance(scores):
  average=grades_average(scores)
  variance=0
  for score in scores:
    variance+=(average-score)**2
  return variance/len(scores)
print (grades_variance(grades))
```

whereas this is correct:

```
def grades_variance(scores):
  average=grades_average(scores)
  variance=0
  for score in scores:
    variance+=(average-score)**2
print (grades_variance(grades))
```

Comment: Umm, the last code snippet you posted prints out `None`. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Here you go: [The return statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)

Comment: @meissner_Make that Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between where I put the 'return'? It gives me a different answer and I'm really confused.

When you call return, you end the function and return execution flow to the calling function. The value you place next to `return` can be considered the *output* of the function.

---

Here is an example function that when called, returns 10 (gives an output of 10):

```
def my_function():
    return 10
```

If I call the function in the console like so:

```
my_function()
```

I will get an output (return value) of 10

If I add a `print` value in the function like so:

```
def my_function():
    print ('This should work')
    return 10
```

Then the function will now print when called.

If I, however, place the print statement after the return statement like so:

```
def my_function():
    return 10
    print ('This should work')
```

Then the function will just output 10 in the console as before and will print nothing. This is because the function has ended before it reaches `print`, and so it never executes.

---

Now for your examples:

```
def grades_sum(scores):
    total=0
    for i in scores:
        total+=i
    return total
    print (total)

grades_sum(grades)
```

For this example, you have placed `print` after `return` in the function. As the execution of the function has been terminated at this point, `print` is not called. If you run the function, it will give you the value that you returned as output (the correct answer as you allowed the function to run through every cycle of the for loop before you exited). So if you run this in the console, you would still see the correct answer. Although this is not the result of your call to `print`.

```
def grades_sum(scores):
  total=0
  for i in scores:
    total+=i
    return total
  print (total)

grades_sum(grades)
```

For this example, return is placed inside the for loop. Everything inside the for loop is called repeatedly for each cycle. However, in this case, on the first cycle of the loop, you call `return`, which as I have mentioned, ends the function. In this case it will return the value of the first score (as only one cycle through the loop was completed before returning). Again, `print` is not called as it is inside the function and is placed after the exit point of the function (after `return`).

Your last 2 examples don't make sense as the last code snippet will not print anything (as the function has no return value). So I am not actually sure what you want from the function. Perhaps edit the question providing a sample of the input data and desired output data.

Answer (score 2):

The `print()` function writes, i.e., "prints", a string in the console.

The `return` statement causes your function to exit and hand back a value to its caller.

The point of functions, in general, is to take in inputs and return something.

The `return` statement is used when a function is ready to return a value to its caller.

For example, here's a function utilizing both `print()` and `return`:

```
def foo():
    print("print foo")
    return "return from foo"
```

Now you can run code that calls foo, like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("before foo")
    x = foo()
    print("after foo")
    print("foo returned - " + str(x))
```

If you run this as a script (e.g. a `.py` file) as opposed to in the Python interpreter, you will get the following output:

```
before foo
print foo
after foo   
foo returned - return from foo
```

---

In your 1st code snippet:

```
def grades_sum(scores):
  total=0
  for i in scores:
    total+=i               #for loop definition
  return total             #return is after for loop completes. 
  print (total)

grades_sum(grades)
```

The `return` is after the `for` loop completes. The `for` loop successfully calculates the some before the `return` statement is encountered and the code flow goes back to the function caller - Hence, it gives correct output.

In your 2nd snippet - `return` is inside the `for` loop. This means the code flow returns after the first iteration itself (& hasn't yet calculated the sum completely) - Hence, this gives incorrect output.

Your example of 3rd & 4th snippet is incorrect as 3rd snippet returns something & 4th doesn't return anything at all - Hence it can't be correcct.

Answer (score 1):

### *"What does `return` do?"*

The `return` statement returns the value to the caller of the function. Here is a simple example:

```
def give_me_a_number():
    return 7
```

Now, `give_me_a_number` will always return `7`, so we can do this:

```
x = give_me_a_number()
```

Variable `x` now has value `7` because that is what `give_me_a_number` returned.

---

### *"What's the difference between where I put the `return`?"*

Where you put the `return` statement is important because statements are executed sequentially and when `return` is encountered, the function ends. For example:

```
def my_function():
    a = 1
    a = 2
    return a
    a = 3
```

Function `my_function` will return value `2`, because that is the value of `a` when `return` is encountered. Note that `a = 3` is never executed.

---

### The code from the question (`return` within `for` loop)

In your case if `return` statement is indented, then it is inside the `for` block and will be executed the first time `for` loop is executed, so that means not all `scores` will be looped through.

```
def grades_sum(scores):
  total=0
  for i in scores:
    total+=i
    return total
  print (total)
```

If it is not indented, then it is outside of the `for` loop and will be executed after the all `scores` are looped though by the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The **first** snippet makes no sense. because your return before printing. Nothing is printed.

The **second** makes no sense because you return in the first loop iteration. The result probably not correct.

I doubt that the **fourth** prints anything but `None`.

Only the **third** snippet returns anything that can be printed.